# blender export gltf for use in three.js - doesn't show smoke and particles

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

i'm trying to export a model to use it in three.js, it's important for me that after import on threejs i can see the smoke effect and the particles, but unfortunately this doesn't happen.

i don't know if is an issue or i'm doing something wrong in my project, so i've attached the blender project and a screenshot of my export settings.

can someone please help me to figure out what's wrong?

[gltf exporter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIu60.png)

in this [github issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/issues/300) you can find the Blender project

Comment: Could you share the glTF output of the exporter? I'm not sure if the glTF importer in three.js supports particle systems though.

Comment: sure... you can find it in the github issue linked in the description

Comment: So any solution to this?